# Angular - how to access class property from one of its methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ng-map

I'm using an ng-map in my markup like this:

```
<ng-map>
    <div ng-repeat="loc in mapsCtrl.locations">
       <marker position="{{loc.position}}" title="{{loc.address}}" on-click="mapsCtrl.showDetails(event, {{loc}})">
       </marker>
    </div>
    <info-window id="cached" template="{{mapsCtrl.infoWindowTemplate}}"></info-window>
</ng-map>
```

... and in my mapsCtrl, the 'showDetails' method is being successfully called when the marker is clicked. Here's the control class:

```
(function() {

    class mapsCtrl {
        constructor(NgMap, mapsSrv, UserInfo) {
            this.NgMap = NgMap;
            ...
        }

        showDetails(event, loc) {
            this.NgMap.showInfoWindow('cached', this);
        }
```

... but in my 'showDetails', 'this' now refers to the marker and I can't access NgMap. How do I reference NgMap?

**UPDATE:**

OK, so I've found that for this *specific use case*, since I have a reference to the marker, this works, in showDetails:

```
showDetails(event, loc) {
   this.map.showInfoWindow('cached', this);
}
```

I'm still not clear though on why 'this' refers to the marker and not the control. Can someone please explain what's happening there?

Comment: It looks like what is happening is that your on-click event is acting like a jQuery click event and is passing a reference to the HTML element the event is bound to instead of the class reference. I have never used NgMap though, so just a thought.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't 'this' in a class member always refer to the class though? This is what's confusing me.

Comment: Normally, yes. Maybe changing to `ng-click` would work as expected.